# How to manage dataframe within Streamlit (hosted on Heroku)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heroku, streamlit

I would like to build a simple web app to do some data analysis, with Python + Streamlit + Heroku.

In my idea, I would like to be able to add/edit/delete entries from the dataframe, but most importantly save it somewhere. I don't really know where and how to store it.

I can't just have it as a file on the repo, because I think it would be modified everytime I push new changes (the local wouldn't be updated as the remote one), am I right?

What is the correct way to do this? Rely on some kind of sheet hosted somewhere else and fetch every time from it (GSheet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at firestore? It's quite easy to use and there are instructions on the blog.

https://blog.streamlit.io/streamlit-firestore/

Comment: I'll look into it, seems exactly what I needed!

Comment: Please accept the answer if you believe I have answered it.